# verilog parameter value at compile time

Tags: verilog

I have a design which goes like this

```
module A #(parameter SIZE=2) ( input i, output j);
wire [0:SIZE-1]i;
// some statements
........
........
endmodule
```

I compile this design.

Next a I make a testbench for this

```
module A_test()
// instantiate A
reg [0:7]i; 
wire [0:7]j;

A #(8) (i,j);
// some statements
............
............
endmodule
```

My question is now that the parameter that is being passed to design `A` has changed, while compiling the testbench is the design also recompiled with new parameter value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The empirical method:

A.v:

```
module A #(parameter SIZE=2) (
  input [SIZE-1: 0 ]i
);
  initial begin
    $display("SIZE : %d", SIZE);
  end
endmodule
```

A_TOP.v:

```
module A_TOP();
  reg [0:7]i; 

  A #(8) u_A ( .i(i) );
endmodule
```

Run at A module level

```
irun A.v    
  SIZE: 2
```

Run at A_TOP level

```
irun A_TOP.v
  SIZE: 8
```

FYI when running the last section this is part of the log file:

```
Generating native compiled code:
            worklib.A:v <0x19d5a0ff>
                    streams:   1, words:   516
            worklib.A_TOP:v <0x748867a4>
                    streams:   0, words:     0
```

So yes it does recompile the module.